# specific date string format

Tags: java, date

I am getting dates as strings from a web service.
They are in the following string format.
`"2016-04-12 12:18:11.000 EDT"`
The documentation is not very good but I guess this is some standard date format.
Do you recognize this format?
How can I most easily parse it into a `Date`?

Comment: Actually the documentation is really good, it even comes with a [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: I meant the web service documentation. Wow, 4 downvotes... This is crazy. Thanks a bunch. People are really helpful in the SO Java tag.

Comment: You have a gold badge in Java and don't know how to search for parsing String to Date? This is what I would call "Wow".

Comment: I guess the down-votes are from wondering which part of that string is confounding you. `2016` looks like a year. `04` and `12` are then obviously month and day. `12:18:11` sure looks like a time, and `.000` is millisecond. `EDT` is very likely US "Eastern Daylight Time".

Comment: @Tom Forget about it.

Answer (score 3):

I think its either `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS zzz` or `yyyy-dd-MM HH:mm:ss.SSS zzz`

from your example 2016-04-12,it can be 12th april,2016 or 4th december 2016

simple example by considering `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS zzz`

```
DateFormat gmtFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS zzz");
    TimeZone gmt = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT");
    gmtFormat.setTimeZone(gmt);
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S");
    Date dd = df.parse("2016-04-12 12:18:11.000 EDT");
    System.out.println( gmtFormat.format(dd));
```

output:**2016-04-12 06:48:11.000 GMT**

Comment: The month comes first in my case, thanks. I will try it out.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
String date = "2016-04-12 12:18:11.000 EDT";
DateFormat parseFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS z", Locale.US);
Date d = parseFormat.parse(date);
```

Locale is important if your system is in a different language.

Answer (score 1):

use this pattern:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS z");


y   Year (e.g. 12 or 2012). Use either yy or yyyy.
M   Month in year. Number of M's determine length of format (e.g. MM, MMM or MMMMM)
d   Day in month. Number of d's determine length of format (e.g. d or dd)
H   Hour of day, 0-23 (normally HH)
m   Minute in hour, 0-59 (normally mm)
s   Second in minute, 0-59 (normally ss)
S   Millisecond in second, 0-999 (normally SSS)
z   Time Zone
```

Comment: Another answer suggests zzz instead of z (for time zone). What is the difference?

Comment: actually no difference. one `z` is enough.